# C# List<T> with standard values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with `List<T>` and really need some help...

Example of code:

```
List<T> myFirstList = new List<T>(); 
myFirstList.Add(new T());
myFirstList.Add(new T());

List<T> mySecondList = new List<T>(); 
mySecondList.Add(new T());
mySecondList.Add(new T());

foreach (T myT in mySecondList)
{
   List<T> myThirdList = myFirstList;
   myThirdList.Add(new T());
}
```

In the second loop from `foreach (T myT in mySecondList)` my variable `myFirstList` contains the value which was added in the first loop.

The actual question is:

**How can I use `myFirstList` in every `loop` with just the two added Items?**

I want to add values to `myThirdList` depending on the items in `List` two. 
But every `List` hast standard values which should be contained every time.

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: `mycontrol.myList = myFirstList.ToList()` ?

Comment: Going by your code, third list will have 3 elements regardless of what lies in second list

Comment: It really isn't clear what you're asking. Can you rephrase the question to clarify exactly what you're trying to achieve and what you've already tried?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're after but would mySecondList.AddRange(myFirstList.ToList()) do the job? This will allow you to append the first to your second and then the second to the third

Comment: @It'satrap well but it does not.. thats the problem..

Comment: Whatever you were saying was wrong. Open this url https://theonlinecompiler.com/ide/250/quiescent-life. The code you wrote above would perfectly work if written properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to replace `mycontrol.myList = myFirstList;` this piece of code with that `mycontrol.myList = new List<T>(myFirstList);`

Comment: If you are not sure,please add this as a comment